# Running BitsTransfer from Local Service account

Tags: powershell, download

I am working on making some scripts to make my job a little bit easier.
One of the things i need is too download some files to use. I first used powershell with the command Invoke-WebRequest.

It is working really well, however it dont run on windows 7 computeres, as they have powershell 2. As i have about as many windows 7 pc's as win 10 i need to find another way.

I found that Start-BitsTransfer is a good way that should work on most computeres. My problem now is, that when using the script via my remote support session it runs the script on the local service account, and then BitsTransfer wont run and gives me an error. (0x800704DD)

Is there a way to get around that problem, or any command that can be used on both win 7 and 10 and run from the local service account?

Comment: Why not update the PowerShell version on the Windows 7 machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also agree that you should not continue supporting PowerShell 2.0. Ideally, ditch Windows 7 (it's way too old now), if you can't do that, upgrade PowerShell, if you can't do that, find a new job, if you can't do that, then I guess bring on the workarounds!

[postanote's answer covers the BITS angle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090210/3905079).

The other thing you can do is just use the .Net framework's underlying libraries, which is exactly what `Invoke-RestMethod` and `Invoke-WebRequest` do (those cmdlets were introduced in PowerShell 3.0, but the guts of them were around much longer).

```
try {
    $wc = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.DownloadFile($url, $path)
finally {
    $wc.Dispose()
}
```

Most people don't bother disposing `IDisposable` objects in PowerShell so you'll see a lot of shorthand around like this:

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

Which is probably fine if your script's process isn't going to be around for a while, but it's good to keep in mind in case you incorporate this into something of a larger scale.

Comment: I cant stop supporting win 7, so i need a workaround. I have tried with your suggestion before, it gives me an error as well: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Comment: Never mind. I wrote it wrong. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You should update PowerShell as [gms0ulman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039142/gms0ulman) states, but if you are not the person who is in charge of this decision, you have to take other steps.

This error code...

> 0x800704DD

The error message ERROR_NOT_LOGGED_ON, occurs because the System Event Notification Service (SENS) is not receiving user logon notifications. BITS (version 2.0 and up) depends on logon notifications from Service Control Manager, which in turn depends on the SENS service. Ensure that the SENS service is started and running correctly.

By default, BITS runs under the LocalSystem account. To modify, stop or restart BITS, you must be logged on as an administrator. In your situation, when you log on a regular account and start the PS in elevated privilege, the BITS doesn’t run under regular user account. To resolve it, you may need to configure the log on user for BITS. Please visit the following link to configure how a service is started.

> Configure How a Service is Started
>
> Services are often run with default settings — for example, a service
>   may be disabled automatically at startup. However, you can use the
>   Services snap-in to change the default settings for a service. This is
>   useful if you are troubleshooting service failures or if you need to
>   change the security account under which a service runs. Membership in
>   Account Operators or Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins, or equivalent,
>   is the minimum required to complete this procedure. Review the details
>   in "Additional considerations" in this topic.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755249(v=ws.10)